# npm install throwing error related to ssl

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am kind of new at this. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

`PS C:\Project Code\ssp-ui-app> npm install`

> npm ERR! code EPROTO npm ERR! syscall write npm ERR! errno EPROTO npm
> ERR! request to
> https://codeload.github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/tar.gz/e865e37af9f9947ddcced76b549e27dc45c1cb2e
> failed, reason: write EPROTO 045D0000:error:0A000152:SSL
> routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation
> disabled:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\extensions.c:908: npm
> ERR!

Comment: This most likely is due to the version of node you are using. Please post your versions of npm and node : `npm --version`  `node --version`

Comment: npm : 8.3.0, node: v17.1.0

Comment: @AitiK Hello, I am having the same problem as you. Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score -4):

Update your node.js installation.The following commands should do it (from here):

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

or reinstall node, then update npm.

First I removed node

```
apt-get purge node
```

Then install node according to the distibution. Docs here .

Then

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```